# OneNote Screen Clipping Shortcut Key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, microsoft-onenote-2013

Using Office 2007 or above with Windows 7, you can press the Windows Key + S to start a screen clipping.  With OneNote 2013 on Windows 8/10, you must now press Windows Key + N -> S.  This often negates the usefulness, since the point (for me, at least) is to capture the view of an open menu or drop-down.

Is there a way to revert back to the old Windows Key + S to begin a OneNote Screen Clipping?  I have already tried [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/descapa/archive/2006/11/17/changing-the-onenote-screen-clipping-and-new-side-note-keyboard-shortcuts.aspx), which is apparently out of date (2006), and Google has not been very helpful in this regard.

Comment: @Ramhound ah, so you did.  Could not find that either, but was not searching for anything with Cortana, so that might have been my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per [the comments in this article](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/screen-clipping-shortcut-onenote-windows-8-1), you can use Shift + Windows Key + S to do this.